# ReadLine[file] after reopening a closed stream doesn't read at the beginning of file?

Tags: bugs, streams

Take a text file from your system:

```
file = OpenRead["path/to/your/file"]

ReadLine[file]

Close[file]
```

Here `ReadLine[file]` should return the first line from the file. Now reopen the closed stream and read a line again:

```
file = OpenRead["path/to/your/file"]

ReadLine[file]
```

I'd expect to get the first line again. However, in my system this returns the **second** line of the file. That is, closing a file and reopening it doesn't reset the read position.

Is this supposed to happen? From my usage of other languages such as C++ I'd expect that closing and reopening a file should reset the reading position to the beginning of the file.

**Edit:** I am using Mathematica 10.0.2, Ubuntu 14.04.1.

**Edit 30/1/20159:** This is clearly unwanted behavior. I have added the tag **bug**. I have not been able to contact Wolfram support because their webpage freezes for me for some reason, so please some else make the bug report.

Comment: in addition to the noted bug `ReadLine` is inexplicably throwing a "cannot be used with binary data" error on files that are absolutely plain text. If they ever pick up the phone on the issue let then know about that too.

Comment: This seems OS-specific. I don't reproduce this with versions 10.4.1 and 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as un-reproducible.

Comment: This bug is fixed in V11.3

Comment: @JasonB. Did you try with Mathematica 10.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Read[file, String]` instead of `ReadLine[file]`.

[image]

Comment: I'm using version 10.0.2, what version are you on?

Comment: See edit for my system version.

Comment: Yes in the latest version `ReadLine` has a few flaws.

Answer (score 1):

I find that an error occurs when you try to get ReadLine (giving it the filename) to open a file subsequent times.  For example here with Linux MMA 11.1.1:

```
ReadLine["/tmp/numbers.txt"]
```

Out:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

So far so good.  Now I close the file:

```
Close["/tmp/numbers.txt"]
```

Out:

```
/tmp/numbers.txt
```

Now I try to reopen the file:

```
ReadLine["/tmp/numbers.txt"]
```

Out:

```
Read::openx: InputStream[/tmp/numbers.txt,3] is not open.
```

Don't know if that happens on any other operating system.  Seem to get around 
it by manually opening the file first:

```
file = OpenRead["/tmp/numbers.txt"];
ReadLine[file]
Close[file];
```

Comment: Have you reported this to the tech support?

Comment: I haven't Alexey as I tend to use OpenRead anyway, but yourself (or anybody) are quite welcome to :)